# How to remove chrome extensions panel?

Tags: google-chrome

I recently started to see a new panel from chrome extensions pan, it hides my active extension. How can I remove the the new chrome extension panel?

[image: Image for chrome extension pan]

Comment: This is a new feature in Chrome. There's no way to control it from an extension. You can disable it in `chrome://flags` but the ability to disable will be removed soon.

Comment: what is the flag name ?

Comment: disabling "Extensions Toolbar Menu" flag removed the pan. thanks!!!